# Xamarin Webview ' Webpage not available ' error, how to show custom error message

Tags: xamarin, webview, error-handling, xamarin.android

This is the acitivity code.

```
namespace LoadWebPage {
    [Activity(Label = "LoadWebPage", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our webview and load the local file in for display
            WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LocalWebView);
            webView.SetWebViewClient (new WebViewClient ());
            webView.LoadUrl("http://www.xamarin.com");

            // Some websites will require Javascript to be enabled
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            //webView.LoadUrl("http://youtube.com");

            // allow zooming/panning            
            webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
            webView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);

            // scrollbar stuff            
            webView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay; 
            // so there's no 'white line'            
            webView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `WebViewClient` and implement both `OnReceivedError` methods and then create an instance of the `WebViewClient` subclass and assign it via the `WebView.SetWebViewClient` method.

When you receive an error, post a native AlertDialog, custom popup, or redirect the WebView to custom error page, etc...

#### WebViewClient subview:

```
public class Client : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnReceivedError(WebView view, ClientError errorCode, string description, string failingUrl)
    {
        DisplayError(view, description);
    }

    // API 21+
    public override void OnReceivedError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
    {
        DisplayError(view, error.Description);
    }

    void DisplayError(WebView view, string description)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(view.Context, description, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        view.LoadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
webView.SetWebViewClient(new Client());
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, but still not able to solve it, this is my solution https://gitlab.com/arun22.chief/LoadWebPage.git can you take a look, pls

Comment: @EdathadanChiefakaArun What is the `net::` error that is being displayed in the error page?

Comment: I get a blank webview if i start the app with network turned off.  if I load the first page with network turned on, then I turn network off, the links dont work, no error message shown.

Comment: @EdathadanChiefakaArun You are describing a different problem now, use a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it with an `IntentFilter` (`ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction`) to monitor the network connectivity and act accordingly upon connection changes....

Comment: In mobile phone 'no webpage available' error is shown, in emulator error is not displayed just, just blank.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3LV2I6A-ccfcWVvN1dXLVR5THM   this is the compressed solution. I want to show a custom error when the network in not available when navigating inside a webview.

Comment: @EdathadanChiefakaArun Use a BroadcastReceiver and register it with an IntentFilter (ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction) to monitor the network connectivity, when you are disconnected, disable the WebView and  display an `AlertDialog` that a network connection is required by your app to continue.

Comment: I did this and set the fallbac url to `index`, but now the application falls in an infinite loop of loading the homepage, hitting an error and loading the homepage again.